# Saving Android sdk's to external hard drive for mac users

Tags: java, android

Can android sdk's be moved to a external hard drive for mac users (if that really matters)? I have went to Android Studio-> Preferences-> Appearances and Behavior -> Android Sdk and tried to browse to external hard drive but cannot. Any suggestions or confirmed solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK is entire portable. You should mount the volume  in a directory the IDE can access

Otherwise go to the /Volumes folder

Comment: Thanks for answer. Need just a bit more guiding. Are you suggesting mount Android Studio (IDE) to a external hard drive and now it can read the external drive?

Comment: Took a second look at it. You (cricket_007) awesome man! I went to the same directory path as in the question and browsed down to the Volume folder and bam, there was my external hard drive! Thanks a lot!